unable to update service account password for windows service on remote database server
I am trying to update service account password for windows service(example: SQL service) on remote server but keeps getting following error. I am using PowerShell version 7.0 which supports -Credential as parameter for Set-Service
Error:

Set-Service: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Credential'.

Script:
$servers = Get-Content "C:\folder\servers.txt"

$ServiceName = read-host "Enter Service Name Here"

$Cred = Get-Credential
$Username = $Cred.username
$Password = $Cred.GetNetworkCredential().password

foreach ($server in $servers){
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
get-service $using:ServiceName | stop-service 
$svc = Set-Service -Name $using:ServiceName -Credential $using:Cred
if ($svc)
{$OUT = "$Using:server Service Account Password Change Succeed"
$OUT}
else {$OUT = "$Using:server Service Account Password Change Failed"
$OUT}
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
get-service $using:ServiceName | Start-service
}}



Even when starting from PS Core+, you may enter into Windows PowerShell when you initiate PS Remoting. See this SO post for more details.
Confirm you're in PS Core in the remote session too by printing $PSVersionTable in your payload script.
You can do the legwork to enable/configure the PS Core endpoints on your target, or you can invoke pwsh.exe with the -File or -Command arguments to pass your script payload to the correct runtime as a workaround.

Thanks. I found few servers had v5.0 so script was failing.
